# Unicode not displaying correctly in my page

Tags: php, html, unicode, character-encoding

In my html5 page, around 80% of the strings are unicode. Worked perfectly with my local server. When uploaded to my online server, the pages are not displaying the unicode contents  correctly. Instead, they are all questions marks!

I have already set the meta tag when I started coding the pages:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

On checking the response headers received on Chrome browser, the "utf-8" encoding was not present. So I added the php `header()` to sent HTTP headers like this:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Now, the response header is showing up the utf-8 encoding, but the page is not rendering the unicode strings. Still its question marks!

I used the File Manager present in my cPanel (of online server), and it opens up utf-8 encoded page and rendered perfectly, when I choose for the online editing of the page! So, that means the uploading of files didn't got messed up. Right ?

I've also tried this meta tag(replacing the short one) :

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Still no use! The unicode content is not from a database. It is completely hardcoded on the page.

Tested with Google Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. All are showing the same ! Any ideas on where should I tweak ?

My server is a VPS provided by HostGator.

Comment: can show an example of these pages?

Comment: Thanks Akam. Found the solution by setting the encoding to utf-8 without BOM. :)

Comment: @halfer: Thanks, will follow that procedure from next time onwards. :)

Comment: @halfer: done. Have a look at the answer below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it works, but you can also try converting your file encoding to UTF-8 (without BOM).

Comment: ghosh! I'm such an idiot! :P Tried every other possibilities and missed this one! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is provided by Lisa Miskovsky (check her answer above/below this post). Thanks Lisa.

What I did was, changed the Encoding by going to the `Encoding` menu bar and then selecting Encoding in `UTF-8 Without BOM`, in my Notepad++ Editor. Sending HTTP header explicitly is also not needed now(just tested). I think, it would consider the meta tag for charset because of the absence of the HTTP headers.